# Unable to Set pins high or low on JDY-23 Bluetooth 5.0 BLE Module

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use JDY-23 Bluetooth 5.0 BLE Module. I am able to send AT commands from my computer. When I try to use NRF mobile connect app to control output pins on the module I have to use 0xFFE2 UUID service but the NRF Mobile app only shows 0xFF01 service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog post https://blog.csdn.net/qq_38335331/article/details/128065874 (You can select right click and use translate if you can't read Chinese)you need to ask the manufacture for the version of JDY-23 that supports FFE2. The IO pins are pretty much useless without that, probably why these modules are so cheap. If you can live with just the serial port function, that does work.